# How to get PHP to read csv file from C: drive

Tags: php, file-io

I want to use PHP to read a CSV (comma separated values) file from the windows `C:` drive `C:\downloads`.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
$file = "c:\\downloads\\test.csv";
$f = fopen($file, "r");
while ($record = fgetcsv($f)) {
    foreach($record as $field) {
        echo $field . "<br>";
    }
}
fclose($f);
?>
```

However, I am getting the following warnings:

```
Warning: fopen(c:\downloads\test.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in /home/content/99/10187599/html/csvread.php on line 3

Warning: fgetcsv() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given 
in /home/content/99/10187599/html/csvread.php on line 4

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in 
/home/content/99/10187599/html/csvread.php on line 9
```

I am following this example from http://phpmaster.com.

How do I read a csv file from the local disk in PHP?

Comment: PHP can not read files form clients machine, files should be in server.

Comment: Try using `/` as directory separator. Or straight `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. Depends on a system.

Comment: @Jan, do you mean / instead of the way I have it presently (\)?